# Как правильно организовать структуру файлов в MVP

Tags: java, mvp

При попытке написать приложение, применяя паттерн MVP, у меня вышло такая структура папок (я еще использовал модули для Google Guice. И я знаю, что есть Dagger 2):

```
com.dugin.rostislav
         |-----model
                 |-----ImageCreater.class
                 |-----ImageCreaterImpl.class
                 |-----ImageChanger.class
                 |-----ImageChangerImpl.class
                 |-----ImageDeleter.class
                 |-----ImageDeleterImpl.class
                 |-----ImageJSONHelper.class
         |-----presenter
                 |-----MainPresenter.class
                 |-----MainPresenterImpl.class
                 |-----ImageCreatePresenter.class
                 |-----ImageCreatePresenterImpl.class
                 |-----ImageChangePresenter.class
                 |-----ImageChangePresenterImpl.class
                 |-----ImageDeletePresenter.class
                 |-----ImageDeletePresenterImpl.class
         |-----view
                 |-----ImageCreateView.class
                 |-----ImageCreateActivity.class
                 |-----ImageChangeView.class
                 |-----ImageChangeActivity.class
                 |-----ImageDeleteView.class
                 |-----ImageDeleteActivity.class
                 |-----MainView.class
                 |-----MainActivity.class
```

Но, при накоплении классов, это все стало разростаться. Ладно еще каталог `model`: в нем можно сделать папку `creaters`, a в ней папку `interfaces` и скинуть туда интерфейсы, чтобы не было кучи из классов. Однако, что делать с каталогами `presenter` и `view`, они же начнут разростаться...

---

Как правильно организовать структуру файлов и катлогов в MVP, чтобы все не превращалось в кучу, а было логически разделено?

Comment: Предложил бы такой вариант: создать несколько каталогов `main`, `image`, `other`, и внутри каждого ваши каталоги `model/presenter/view`.

Comment: как вариант в каждом из пакетов сделать разбивку по функциональности, например, пакет содержащий классы связанные с удалением изображения, созданием, изменением и пр.